# Tuples as function parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this old code that I'm trying to convert from 2.7 to 3 but I cant figure out how to pass some tuple parameters.

Here is the code:

```
def make_dis(self):
    if self.ds == "SEP_EU":
        def metric((x, y), (a, b)): # <- Error here (Invalid syntax)
            return math.sqrt((x - a) ** 2 + (y - b) ** 2)
    else:
        def metric(a, b):
            return 0
    self.n_dist = [[metric(self.n_coord[i], self.n_coord[j]) for i in range(self.dim)] for j in range(self.dim)]
    return self
```

How can I make metric function accept those parameters?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "define" tuples in function parameters, but you can expand them afterwards:

```
def metric(t1, t2):  # Where t1 and t2 are two tuples
    (x, y), (a, b) = t1, t2
    return math.sqrt((x - a) ** 2 + (y - b) ** 2)
```

Besides, with "tuple" expansion in variable assignment, you can actually expand any `Iterable` (not limited to `tuple`s). So your function will still work if you pass a `list` of two:

```
metric([1, 2], [4, 6])  # => 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you @iBug it works great (must wait 10 minutes to accept the answer)